# How to create a Junit Test Class and run in executable JAR

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have a Junit Test Project and I have been on your site finding answers on how to get my program to run from a command prompt.

I can supply the code.  I added a main method to the code that has the test class.  I found an example that has this code in the main method:
JUnitCore jCore = new JUnitCore();
jCore.run();

But all that executes is the main method and not the test.   All of the other examples I see include the name of the class, bu when I add that to the command above it gives me an error.  I think it is because the main method is within the test class.   My programs are .java and not .class so I at a lost as to what to do now.

I am not finding anything that shows the complete steps.  Should also add that I have not done Java for over 13 years so I am rusty.

Here is the code I tried:

```
public class Selenium_Email_TestCase {

private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("In main method");
    JUnitCore jCore = new JUnitCore();
    jCore.run(Selenium_Email_TestCase);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the class object.

```
jCore.run(Selenium_Email_TestCase.class);
```

Don't forget to import `Selenium_Email_TestCase` if it resides in a different package.

Comment: Do I just add that??  I am not sure how to create the .class file from eclipse.   If I do a clean on the project I still do not see .class files in my directory.   How do I know where they are??

Comment: No need to answer the last question.  I just added the .class like you said, created my executable JAR file and rant it.  Worked beautifully.  Thanks Stefan!!!